# Why is the else statement executed after the if when the if is true?

Tags: javascript

The following code：

```
var aa = 1;
if (aa == 1){
    console.log("true")
}
else (aa == 2)
{
    console.log("false")
}
```

prints:

> true
>   false

please tell me why?

Comment: because javascript thinks the else statement is `(aa == 2)` and that everything after that is just a "compound" statement to console.log false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not valid if statement see

```js
var aa = 1;
if (aa == 1){
    console.log("true")
}//see next line you miss if after else
else if(aa == 2)
{
    console.log("false")
}
```

Comment: Gladto help you :)

Answer (score 3):

With proper formatting, your code is actually this:

```
var aa = 1;

if (aa == 1) {
    console.log("true")
} else {
    (aa == 2);
}

{
    console.log("false")
}
```

The last block with the log statement is not associated with the `if..else` at all. You're missing the `if` in `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 'mistakes' in code, your code executes as

```
var aa = 1;
if (aa == 1) {
    console.log("true")
} else {(aa == 2)}

{
    console.log("false")
}
```

and right code is

```
var aa = 1;
if (aa == 1) {
    console.log("true")
} else if (aa == 2) {
    console.log("false")
}
```